# CardView with RecycelView getting me blank white screen

Tags: android

So I have this kind of error I have Adapter to recycle view and a CardView and it showing empty white screen.

I got it all from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL1VpGBj3R0&t=1147s

[Adapter.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T25iD.jpg)

[destenation.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnWhZ.jpg)

[Activity_destenation.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVbCR.jpg)

[CardView.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz8aB.jpg)

[item.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdaiN.jpg)

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found from your codes are:

Your method:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

always returns 0, because of which data is not populating in the Recycler View.

Change your method to:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
```

It should work.

Comment: ty is fixed my app :)